# how to get value from span through javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<span class="modalclass" value="<? $product_name; ?>" onClick="alert(this.value)">hi
    <button type="button"  id="myBtnaa" value="<?= $product_id; ?>" onClick="alert(this.value)">BUY NOW</button>
</span>
```

When i click the span, not alerting the value($product_name) from span.It says undefined. In case of button it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php script was not executed as you failed to use `<??>` or `<?=?>`:

```
value="<?=$product_id?>"
```

and

```
value="<?=$product_name?>"
```

Note that span don't have `value` attribute. Also its is not recommended to have inline `onclick` for nested elements. Try out HTML 5 `data-*` instead.

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<span data-value="Hello" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('data-value'))" class="btn">Click me</span>
```

Comment: sorry i forgoted to add php tag in question. now i updated my question.

Comment: @sreechithsrk - You're still missing the `echo` (or the short version like in this example, `<?=`) in your code. Without that, the value won't actually be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

Note that span don't have value attribute, so I have replaced it to `data-value`

```html
<span class="modalclass" data-value="<?=$product_name?>" onClick="alert(this.getAttribute('data-value'))">
hi
    <button type="button"  id="myBtnaa" value="<?=$product_id?>" onClick="alert(this.value)">BUY NOW</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing product name through span and product id through button . Why ? JQuery / AJAX is a very strong tool for developers which ease out their lives , and you are making it complicated . If you want to display the product name and id on the page , display it in span , otherwise make it display: none . Check the code below :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtnaa").on('click', function(){
        var text = document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML ;
        var res = text.split("|") ;
        alert(res[0]) ;
        alert(res[1]) ;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:-

```
<span class="modalclass" id="myspan" style="display:none;"><?php echo "8|Maggi Noodles" ; /*This value can come from two variables*/ ?></span>

<button type="button"  id="myBtnaa">BUY NOW</button>
```